# In Jira, how do I roll up Story Points or Time expended to Initiative?

Tags: jira

In my JIRA project, we have the following issue hierarchy:
Sub-tasks > Stories > Epics > Initiatives

Most of our estimates and tracking happen at the Story level:

- Story Points are recorded on Stories
- Time estimates are recorded on Stories or Sub-tasks

I am hoping to run some reports aggregating up the Initiative level, to report on story points per initiative (per time frame) and actual time spent.   Would love any advice or recommendations on how to do that!

Answer (score 2):

If you are using story points, then you should not estimate with time (You will probably not like this answer :)).

For an epic, Jira sums up the points of all stories related to it, so it's straightforward to report total points.

If you need the time estimate at a high level for reporting purposes, you should rely on the velocity of the team. Then, you can provide roadmap kind of time estimates for your backlog.

Comment: Story points are related to relative sizing technique, so yeah!! team velocity has to be considered.